# Pandas で条件付けした列の抽出をしたい

Tags: python, python3, pandas

3つの変数(A,B,C)から成るdfから C=True(Cはbool)に限定した、変数をAとBのみに限定した新たなdf1を作成する際のコードについてですが、下記を考えましたがエラーになります。どこがおかしいのでしょうか？どなたかご教示ねがえないでしょうか？ それとも１行で記載するのは難しいのでしょうか？

```
df1 = df[['A', 'B']].query('C == True')
df1
```

Comment: `df[['A', 'B']]` としているので、`C` 列が含まれていません。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

コメントに解が記されてるけどそういうことです
他の方法も ↓

```py
display(df.loc[df['C'], ['A', 'B']])
display(df[df['C']][['A', 'B']])

df1 = df.query('C == True')[['A', 'B']]
# df1 = df.query('C')[['A', 'B']]   # これも可能かも？
```

Comment: boolean だから `df1 = df.loc[df['C'], ['A', 'B']]` でいいんじゃないの。

Comment: @metropolis なるほどそうですね

Comment: df1 = df.query('C == True')[['A', 'B']]   で解決しました！ あれこれ悩んでいたのですが、皆さまに助けて頂きました！ありがとうございました。